# gsutil: why ls returns directory itself

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I got

```
$ gsutil ls gs://ml_models_c/ref7/test/model/2/
gs://ml_models_c/ref7/test/model/2/                        <= why this?
gs://ml_models_c/ref7/test/model/2/saved_model.pb
gs://ml_models_c/ref7/test/model/2/variables/
$ gsutil ls gs://seldon-models/tfserving/mnist-model/1/
gs://seldon-models/tfserving/mnist-model/1/saved_model.pb
gs://seldon-models/tfserving/mnist-model/1/variables/
```

Why there is `gs://ml_models_c/ref7/test/model/2/` in the first command output?
Why the second command does not return itself?

It seems that I can rm it.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @BAE could you please confirm if you don't have a file with the same name of the directory? In this case, a file with the name `2`? Searching around, it seems that it might be related to this bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72439262).

Answer (score 1):

At the API level, Cloud Storage doesn't have the concept of folders, everything is stored as long file names that might have slashes in them.

In this case, you likely have an object named `gs://ml_models_c/ref7/test/model/2/`, but no object named `gs://seldon-models/tfserving/mnist-model/1/`

If you don't need the `gs://ml_models_c/ref7/test/model/2/` object, you can delete it and it will no longer show in the results for `gsutil ls`